# Wordpress show sub menu items on index page

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress and on the page "sidebar.php" I have the following code:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('post_type=wiki&depth=1'); ?>
```

It works great but what I need to do it that what I click on a Menu item on the sidebar I need the sub items to display on the main page.

UPDATE:

What I basically need to do is to have the first level items on the left (As it currently is), and when those links are clicked then the sub items of those items will be listed on the index.php (main page).

I am using the wp-wiki plugin to display the pages as wiki pages but the actual but the list is the same, just showing as a different type:

```
post_type=wiki
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&depth=0');
?>
```

Comment: Where about do I use that code within the index.php please? You you need the index page code?

Comment: place it where ever you want the menu to go. Just try pasting it in, and seeing where it is, and moving it about to get it right.

Comment: Sorry, that's not working. I'll try to explain further: I have 2 pages: sidebar.php width has the first level LI's and uses this code:<li><?php wp_list_pages('post_type=wiki&depth=1'); ?></li> .... then when I click on the first level link on the sidebar menu I want to display the sub menu items from that particular clicked link on the main (index.php) page. I am using wp-wiki plugin to display the list of pages. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: wp-wiki to display the child pages? or the sidebar? I think you should rewrite the question to include the new info.

Comment: Sorry, I am struggling to understand what it not working. Is this site live?

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways you can accomplish this. WordPress actually has an example of *exactly* what you're looking to do in the Codex. ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages) - the last example in that section, right above the "List subpages even if on a subpage" heading)

There's several ways to do this though - that's just one example. But that code above, you just pop into your sidebar.php file.  You can also create a widget out of it.  And as someone else mentioned, you can use the new menu system for WordPress (but you *can* indeed, make it dynamic.)  But the above example in the Codex is the simplest method.

Actually, an easier method would be just to list all subpages and use CSS to hide and show the child items based on what page you're on.  The classes are already set up for you.  Just view your source code and you can see it.  So you'd do something like:

```
`li ul.children {display:none; }
 li.current_page ul.children { display:block; }`
```

and variations thereof.

Comment: Sorry but none of them work. Could it be because the page type has to be wiki?

Comment: I don't believe so.  You have to view your page source to see what the actual classes are for the CSS stuff. but for the wp_list_pages...further down on that page I linked to tells you how to list the Pages for the custom post type. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_members_of_a_custom_post_type) You can use that in combination with the child-page detection stuff.

Comment: Another though... when you use a Custom Post Type, you're writing posts and creating categories - not Pages.  wp_list_pages is for *Pages*.  So I bet we've been giving you the wrong thing - you want wp_list_categories().  If you don't have categories (which many times, by default, people who set up a custom post type do not set up custom taxonomies to go with it, so you may not have any), then you want to have a list of posts/post titles. Is that what's going on? Because if you're using wp_list_pages and your custom post type is for posts, you won't get Page listings.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the new menu function in wp 3?
That way you could include your type with any sub page you want (won't be dynamic though) and then add your favorite javascript or good css to show those sub-pages.